# HTML and Javascript form

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I had a really quick and dumb question. 
Say I have a short form in HTML asking for a username.
Then I'm using Parse to store my users and stuff, but it is in javascript where it creates a var and a Parse.User.
However I want to use the username input in the HTML form as the username instead of "username". But I have no idea how to do that as you can't make variables in HTML. 
Heres the JavaScript Parse uses to make a user (which creates a user with just those hardcoded fields).

```
var user = new Parse.User();

user.set("username", "username");

user.set("password", "my pass");

user.set("email", "email@example.com");
```

Comment: Surround your codes with ticks to format it : `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <form>
  UserName: <input type="text" id="username" /> 
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="password" id="password" /> 
  <br><br>
  Email: <input type="text" id="email" /> <br>
</form>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Sign Up" onclick="signUp();" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxx");

  function signUp() {

    var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", name);
    user.set("password", pass);
    user.set("email", mail);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, issue though it doesn't seem to be doing anything when I hit the button.

Comment: Did you check the developer console if there is any error on your end?

Comment: I don't think there is? pkothar2.github.io Is where I'm testing it

Comment: It seems to be the error in your other code. Could you follow up this one to get it properly fixed: https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript

Comment: Oh definitely, thank you for the help so far, hopefully I can manage to get this figured out.

Comment: I've tried for a while now but haven't been able to figure it out. The Todo app just complicated it as they don't even initialize Parse in it.